# Join(?), group by and two schemas

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query, working fine:

```
select
    order_details.productid,
    count(*)
from order_details
left join orders
    on order_details.orderid = orders.orderid
group by order_details.productid;
```

The thing is I don't really want to get the "productid" but the "productname".

"productname" is in a different schema: adm.

So how can I get result like this?

```
 PRODUCTNAME   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
      table          5
       desk          7
       lamp          4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "other schema" do you mean another table or really another schema? If it is another schema you just need a DB Link if the two schemas are in separate databases or if in the same database just a grant that allows you to select from both schemas.

Without knowing more details it seems like you want to do this:

```
SELECT adm.some_product_table.productname, count(*) 
FROM order_details LEFT JOIN orders on order_details.orderid = orders.orderid
LEFT JOIN adm.some_product_table on adm.some_product_table.productid = order_details.productid
GROUP BY order_details.productid;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! 
The two schemas are in the same db, privileges are ok.
The group by should be followed by adm.some_product_table.productname

Answer (score 0):

You would need another `join`.  However, you need to know the table with the product name and the column for joining.

Something like:

```
select p.productname, count(*)
from order_details od join
     adm.products p                  -- guessing at the name
     on od.productid = p.productid   -- and the column for joining
group by p.productname;
```

I am guessing that you do not need the `orders` table at all in the query.  All order details should be part of exactly one order, if your database is set up correctly.

Comment: Hi , I am just curious will this query work ?
select products.ProductName, count(*) FROM PRODUCTS WHERE productid in (
select OrderDetails.productid
from OrderDetails left 
join orders on OrderDetails.orderid = orders.orderid 
group by OrderDetails.productid
) group by ProductName ;

Comment: It will "work" but probably return "1" for every product.

Comment: orders table is needed for later where conditions. Sorry if it was misleading.

Comment: @STO . . . You can put it back in.  It is not related to the particular question.  And the outer join seems utterly unnecessary, just an limiting factor in optimizing the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
connect adm/pwd1;
grant select on products to this_schema;
connect this_schema/pwd2;
select p.productname, count(*) 
  from order_details d,orders o, adm.products p
 where d.orderid = o.orderid 
   and d.productid = p.productid
 group by p.productname;
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation.